# SDK Manager doesn't show older APIs

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools, android-sdk-manager, android-api-levels

I have installed android studio and android 5.0.1 (API 21) is installed
I am unable to see older APIs. Please check the image below for reference. Please guide me suggestion how to install API 19 when its not shown in SDK Manager.

SDK Manager after fetching the list:

[image: SDK Manager after updating list]

Comment: its still fetching the list, see at the bottom of your screenshot...

Comment: Update the screenshot with one in which all the files have been fetched.

Comment: even after it completes fetching nothing will show

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set proxy in `tools/option` section of your sdk manager and restart it

Comment: what was the problem?

Comment: need to change proxy then only it showed older apis otherwise nothing was showing

Comment: so I think it's better you choose my answer as the best answer in order to inform others about this problem

Comment: i upvoted but stack overflow showing message vote done by less than 15 reputation recorded but not displayed publicly

Comment: you can use the ticker below the voting signs to set it as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

It could be your connection . so try to fix your network connection and restart your IDE